# Python: Output format of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of temperatur measurement:

```
temp = [ [39, 38.5, 38], [37,37.5, 36], [35,34.5, 34], [33,32.5, 32], [31,30.5, 30], [29,28.5, 28], [27,26.5,26] ]
```

every value is recorded every 5 hour over several days. First day is first list of temp:
 `[39, 38.5, 38],` second day is second list of temp: `[37, 37.5, 36]` etc.

What I always do is, I loop over the 'temp' and calculate the time difference between the values and save this as list in time. (The time difference is always 5h)

```
time=[]
for t in temp:
 for i,val in enumerate(t):
         i=i*5
         time.append(i)
print time
```

The output looks like this:

```
time: [0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10]
```

But I want to get sublists of every day, like:

```
time: [ [0, 5, 10] , [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10] ]
```

What`s wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep appending to the same list, you should create a new list for every day.

```
time=[]
for t in temp:
    day_list = [] # Create a new list
    for i,val in enumerate(t):
        i=i*5
        day_list.append(i) # Append to that list
    time.append(day_list) # Then append the new list to the output list
print time
```

For a list comprehension:

```
time = [[i*5 for i, val in enumerate(t)] for t in temp]
```

Comment: @ parchment: Thank you! Can i write the same with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

You are appending all timestamp to a single-level list, so that's what your algorithm outputs.

Here is one way to get a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(range(0, len(t) * 5, 5)) for t in temp]
[[0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10], [0, 5, 10]]
```

This correctly deals with sublists of `temp` potentially having different lengths.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably most what the original asker wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact same thing in each list, do this:

```
time = [[0,5,10] for _ in temp]
```

To account for variable sublist length:

In python 2

```
time = [range(0, len(i)*5, 5) for i in temp]
```

In python 3, must materialize range:

```
time = [list(range(0, len(i)*5, 5)) for i in temp]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a temporary sub list and then append that sublist to the actual list to get a bunch of sublists within a list

```
temp = [ [39, 38.5, 38], [37,37.5, 36], [35,34.5, 34], [33,32.5, 32], [31,30.5, 30], [29,28.5, 28], [27,26.5,26] ]
time=[]
for t in temp:
    l = []
    for i,val in enumerate(t):
        i=i*5
        l.append(i)
        if len(l) == 3:
            time.append(l)
print time
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension, you can do it in one line:

```
time = [[i*5 for i, val in enumerate(t)] for t in temp]
```